# Type Ahead Search - Full Text - Recoll vs DocFetcher OR?

Tags: open-source

i have 1,00,000 documents in doc, docx and txt format. I want all of them to be indexed and looking for the following features

1. Number of hits found before entering the search
2. Type-ahead search results
3. Type-ahead auto complete suggestion for a word or sentence
4. Quick results in a second instead of taking huge time to process the request
5. Quick navigation of the results via keyboard function keys
6. Preview pane to view the results as well as gone through further of the text as well

Any other better open source or freeware available other than recoll, docfetcher, cherry tree or zim wiki.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, have you settled on any programme yet? I currently use Doc Fetcher, but I find the searching slow. I have heard Archivarius is good, but I think it's expensive. I haven't tried it.